# xpath extract URL - Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape the following website: https://bionetz.ch/adressen/detailhandel/bio-fachgeschaefte.html

At the end of my scraper, I would like to integrate a for-loop which automatically goes to the next page.

Of course, I know that there is a "show all-button" which I used for my solution. However, when exploring this website, I wasnt able to extract the href-tag from the website.

The href- tag I need should be in the following "li"

```
<a title="Weiter" href="/adressen/detailhandel/bio-fachgeschaefte/page2.html" class="pagenav"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
```

However, I wasnt able to get it? What would be the xpath to extract it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scrapy shell` for debugging. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html

```
scrapy shell https://bionetz.ch/adressen/detailhandel/bio-fachgeschaefte.html
```

Then we can extract next URL

```
>>> response.xpath("//a[@title='Weiter']/@href").get()                                         
'/adressen/detailhandel/bio-fachgeschaefte/page2.html'
```